# Oracle stored procedure INOUT ARRAY

Tags: spring, stored-procedures

I have Oracle PLSQL procedure with INOUT type as an ARRAY. I am trying to call with simpleJdbcCall.execute method. I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: {my_msg_tbl=org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlArrayValue@3978894a}
>   at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toARRAY (ARRAY.java:230)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical (OraclePreparedStatement.java:8459)

Here is plsql details

```
create or replace TYPE MY_ARRAY_TBL as table of varchar2(5000);
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PROCEDURE AS
PROCEDURE GET_MY_RECORDS ( name VARCHAR2, my_msg_tbl IN OUT MY_ARRAY_TBL);
END MY_PROCEDURE;
```

Java Code:
Simple JDBC call

```
simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withCatalogName("MY_PROCEDURE")
        .withProcedureName("GET_MY_RECORDS")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("name", Types.VARCHAR, "VARCHAR2"),
                           new SqlInOutParameter("my_msg_tbl", Types.ARRAY, "MY_ARRAY_TBL", new SqlReturnArray()));
```

Procedure call:

```
String[] valueArr = new String[1];
valueArr[0] = "some-value";
simpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource("name","test"), Collections.singletonMap("my_msg_tbl", new SqlArrayValue(valueArr)));
```

Any inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Any inputs on the issue is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you remove everything except the direct calls to JDBC? Find the SQL string used to create the CallableStatement, the JDBC call that creates the ARRAY value, the JDBC call to set the parameter value, the JDBC call that executes the SQL and the JDBC call that gets the value of the out parameter. Put that together into a pure JDBC test case and run that.